# Setting the right parent of custom layout

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I have custom `QHBoxLayout`. I add this Layouts to a `QVBoxLayout` of a `QFrame`. Because the `QFrame` already has a layout i cant call the base class constructor of my custom `QHBoxLaout` with the `QFrame` as parent. So i do an addItem to the `QVBoxLayout`. That works fine but when i try to grap my cutom Layout as children i get a `NULL`. If have already to to grap them with `ItemAt()` and `dynamic_cast` the returned ptr to my Custom Layout but thats seems to me very ugly. How do i make it right?

MyLayoutClass.h

```
    class MyLayoutClass : public QHBoxLayout{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MyLayoutClass(const QString& rb_name, const QString& label_name, QWidget * parent = 0);
        QRadioButton * rb;
        QLabel * label;
    };
```

MainWindow.h:

```
    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        QFrame * MyFrame;
    }
```

MainWindow Constructor:

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),MyFrame(nullptr),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        for(int i = 0; i <4; i++)
    {
             MyLayoutClass * addLayout = new MyLayoutClass("Hallo","Welt",this->ui->MyFrame);
            this->ui->MyFrame->layout()->addItem(addLayout);
        }
        MyLayoutClass* child = this->ui->MyFrame->findChild<MyLayoutClass*>();
        if(child==NULL) qDebug()<<"Not a single Child of the Frame";

        child = this->ui->MyFrame->layout()->findChild<MyLayoutClass*>();
        if(child== NULL) qDebug()<<"Not a single Child of Frame Layout";

        MyLayoutClass * first = dynamic_cast<MyLayoutClass*>(ui->MyFrame->layout()->itemAt(0));
        qDebug()<< first->rb->text(); 
    }
```

MyLayoutClass Constructor:

```
    MyLayoutClass::MyLayoutClass(const QString &rb_name, const QString &label_name, QWidget *parent)
    : QHBoxLayout(), rb(nullptr), label(nullptr)
    {
        rb = new QRadioButton(rb_name,parent);
        label = new QLabel(label_name,parent);
```

```
    this->addWidget(rb);
    this->addWidget(label);
}
```

Output: 
"Not a single Child of the Frame"
"Not a single Child of Frame Layout"
"Hallo"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, i have tried some more and Answer is really simple. In constrast to the Constructor of `QHBoxLayout` which only accept a `QWidget` to be parent, the memberfunction `setParent(Q_Object*)` accepts a layout to be parent.
So this line in the `MyLayoutClass` Constructor solved my problem

```
this->setParent(parent->layout());
```

After that the Output is only "Hallo". So my custom Layout is now a child of both the Frame and his vertical Layout. Which was impossible before because the frame had already a Layout. It looks like I have not yet understand it right.